# Android Crashlytics stuck at "Build and run your app"

Tags: android, crashlytics-android

I followed the tutorial exactly (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=1&platform=android#android) and still can't see my app on firebase Crashlytics. here's my configuration:

in root **build.gradle**

```
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'
  }
```

in app **build.gradle**

```
...
apply plugin: "io.fabric"

...
//Firebase
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:18.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.1'
  implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
```

**in Application**

```
Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics());
```

I'm building and running the app on *debug* but nothing is happening, in the logs I see

> I/CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider skipping initialization
>
> I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics Core 2.7.0.33

what could I be missing?

Comment: Crashlytics was migrated to Firebase some time ago

Comment: that's exactly what I'm doing, https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=1&platform=android#android

Comment: @ElJazouli, Have you added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`?

Comment: You should be replacing ```Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics());``` with ```FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);```

Comment: Did you throw an exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone who is facing a similar issue, I have looked for many hours and eventually checked the merged manifest and figured there is a 3rd party library that was actually setting up their own Crashlytics config which overrides mine. So maybe look into that.

I eventually added this to my manifest:

```
<meta-data
    tools:node="remove"
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [**Firebase Crashlytics Docs**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android).

Step 1:  Add this code in your project level build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    // Add the following repositories:
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    maven {
       url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // ...

    // Check for v3.1.2 or higher
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'  // Google Services plugin

    // Add dependency
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'  // Crashlytics plugin


}
}


allprojects {
// ...

repositories {
   // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
   google()  // Google's Maven repository
   // ...
}
}
```

Step 2 :  Add this code in your app-level build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

dependencies {
// ...

// Check for v11.4.2 or higher
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'

// (Recommended) Add Analytics
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.1'

// Add dependency
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
}
```

Make sure you have added google-services.json and running your app in physical device or emulator having google play services.

credit goes to firebase for creating such a helpful docs.

Comment: weird, doesn't seem to work I tried everything, I already have this exact setup, and already have my google-services.json because I already have firebase integrated, just checked if the file is up to date and it is, so don't really know what's going on, firebase console#crashlytics is stuck at Build and run your app

Answer (score 0):

This is Zubair from Fabric/Firebase. Could you try to make individual build and run event on a brand new simulator (where they've not installed/ran this app before). If issue persist, reach out to us AT "support@fabric.io" and include app name/bundle id and firebase project id in the email.

Comment: thanks for the support! I actually found a 3rd party library overriding my config, removing that fixed it.